# Get size of an array in Volt

Tags: arrays, phalcon, volt

In [Volt](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/volt.html) (the template engine for [Phalcon](https://phalconphp.com/en/)) how can I get the number of elements in an array? I've tried `sizeof` and also `count`, `length` and `size` (hoping to stumble upon the correct command).

In this particular instance I'm just interested in whether there are >0 elements but in the future it would be handy to be able to get the actual number.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Length: Counts the string length or how many items are in an array or object

MoreInfo: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/volt.html#filters

```
{{ yourarray_Var|length }}
```

Comment: Ah, I read through that page but obviously not carefully enough, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

See the accepted answer for the most correct solution to this question. This answer gives an example of how to add a php function into volt though.

Working from the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071428/how-can-i-set-up-a-user-defined-function-in-volt-phalcon), I used the following code to add this function to `Volt`.

```
$volt->getCompiler()->addFunction(
    'count',
        function($key)
        {
            return "count({$key})";
        }
);
```

Place this code where you set up your `Volt` engine (e.g. in my services.php file).